# Eonasdan datetimepicker v4 version

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have lot of datetimepicker in my module. Currently I am using bootstrap datetimepicker v3 version. Some issues are there here. So I will try to use the next version. In v4 version lot of problem has been resolved. So please kindly help me what are the js and css files I have include in my jsp page for using the bootstrap datetimepicker v4 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [installation instructions](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) and [manual and demos](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Quoting:

**Minimal Requirements**
jQuery
Moment.js
Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse are required if you're not using the full Bootstrap)
Bootstrap Datepicker script
Bootstrap CSS
Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
Locales: Moment's locale files are [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/master/locale)

**Scripts needed:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/moment.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/transition.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/js/collapse.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

**CSS styles**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
```